# How do I read the hit damage for monsters?

Tags: dnd-5e, damage

I just got the new 5th edition of D&D and I started reading the new mechanics. One puzzles me. I'm trying to understand the Hit Damage. I'll use the Aarakocra from the monster manual. It says for the Talon attack Hit: 4 (1d4+2). Where does the 4 come in? Is it actually damage like  4 damage plus 1d4+2 or is it like says +4 to hit and damage is (1d4+2). I know it's probably a very stupid question but like I said, confused.